# how to create a simple questionnaire using checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a simple multiple choice questionnaire using checkboxes. My only problem is that the scores doesn't seem to appear correctly on the label.

Here's my codes:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    int score = 0;    
        //String A's value came from another form via combobox and button
        string answer1 = AdminForm.answer1;
        //Let checkbox1 be letter A
        if (checkBox1.Text == answer1)
                    {
                        score = score + 1;
                        label23.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
                    }
}
```

Here's my code from the other form:

```
public static string answer1;
    private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                answer1 = comboBox1.Text;
            }
```

The rest of my codes are running smoothly except for this... What I want is that after clicking the submit button after filling out the checkboxes, the scores would appear correctly on a label... I'm not sure where is my error on this... I'd appreciate the help I can get.

Comment: Please read [ask] and realize that we can't look at your screen. Elaborate on _"the scores doesn't seem to appear correctly"_. What do you expect to happen, what actually happens and what have you tried to resolve these differences?

Comment: Do you need to notify the form that the value has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the text in checkBox1.text and answer1 are different i.e. different in case. Usually I prefer using Equals method for string comparison. Try using something like

```
if (checkBox1.Text.Equals(answer1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Hey thanks! It worked! Now I can finish my project smoothly within the 28 day limit.

Comment: @JanChristopherSantos, Under the up/down vote there is a green check. If someone answer you correctly check it to mark the question as anwered and credit the other user :)